# Youtube API v3 search videos by location

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I try to use Youtube v3 api to search videos by location.

For example I try run this example https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&location=37.42307%252C-122.08427&locationRadius=50km&maxResults=10&order=date&_h=2&

But all what I get is just this error "message": "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions." I try to google how to resolve this problem, but no luck with this one. Maybe someone have example url or know how to resolve this problem. Maybe I'm lucking some required parameters. Ty for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you have got the answer for this.
If not then you need to add the `type=video` in query query or `type=video,list` but you need to add this.
You can follow this 
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?locationRadius=50km&order=date&part=snippet&location=37.42307%252C+-122.08427&type=video%252Clist&maxResults=10&_h=1&

Execute and it will show you result.

Happy Coding.!